# How to copy a path in a JSON in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: json, intellij-idea

Is it possible to copy a path in a JSON file? For example in this file:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": "keyC"
    }
  }
}
```

when I am on a `"keyC"` and I would press some hotkey, I'd get an `a.b.c` string in the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist at the moment, there is an [open request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18858), please vote (see also the related issues).

Answer (score 20):

I know this post is old, but I thought I'd give an updated answer.

I came across this question because I was looking for the same thing, then discovered the feature actually exists in WebStorm already (I'm assuming it exists in IntelliJ as well).

Basically, put your cursor on the node you want, and you'll see the path at the bottom of the editor window. Then you can right-click on the path and select "Copy qualified name to clipboard".

Here's an example of doing this from my IDE:

[image]

Comment: I'm able to do this in PyCharm, but surprisingly Webstorm doesn't have this option. Do you know how to enable in there ?

Comment: It could be that your breadcrumbs are turned off. You can check this in File > Settings > Editor > General > Breadcrumbs. There is a checkbox labeled: "Show breadcrumbs", with the option to specify the languages you want to see the breadcrumbs for. You can also change the placement to Top or Bottom.

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut instead of clicking mouse? And is there the other way around (finding in JSON by path) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179003/how-to-search-by-path-in-a-json-in-intellij-idea?

Comment: Yes. My mapping is currently set to: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C. I'm not sure if that's the default, but you can see yours by navigating to Edit > Copy Reference. 

As far as going the other way around, I haven't seen a way. However, I am able to use: Navigate > File Structure (or use the keyboard mapping for it), and it will bring up a tree structure of the JSON tree, which can be searched and traversed easily.

Comment: Interesting, my breadcrumbs were set to on, but I wasn't seeing them. They were set to bottom. I changed it to top, and boom there they were at top. 

And then I changed setting again to Bottom and boom they were there at the bottom. But they weren't there before. 

Kooky. Tip for others. BTW This is on MacOS w/ IJ 2022.2.2