# How to search by path in a JSON in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: json, intellij-idea

I have very long JSON file for example:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": "keyC"
    }
  }
}
```

And path: `a.b.c`

How to search (go to line) in JSON using path?

Question similar to [How to copy a path in a JSON in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213819/how-to-copy-a-path-in-a-json-in-intellij-idea) but the other way around (path to place in JSON instead of place in JSON to path).

Comment: Do you want Java code to do that?

Comment: No. I looking for only IDE IntelliJ functionality. For example how to Ctrl+F in JSON file with path.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9775-json-utils/

Comment: This plugin isn't very convenient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179003/how-to-search-by-path-in-a-json-in-intellij-idea/59179160#comment104603720_59179160

Answer (score 3):

I had the same need and there was nothing on the marketplace, but now the following one is available and does exactly what you are looking for:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15064-json-key-finder

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is pretty handy. No plugins required.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/evaluate-json-path-expressions/

You can just type stuff like `$.address.country` and select the output type "Matching values"

Comment: Thanks. This is this the same functionality as in this plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179003/how-to-search-by-path-in-a-json-in-intellij-idea/59179160#comment104603720_59179160 You can find value in JSON, but you can't jump to source in file where the value is (common "find" functionality). Aside from that, you're right, it's better from previous solution because it doesn't require a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There's an IntelliJ plugin called "JSON Utils" that looks like it might do what you want. I haven't tried it myself.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9775-json-utils/

Comment: With this plugin I have to open window "JSON Util", copy and paste content of my whole JSON file, type path and I finally get cut out JSON fragment found by path. This is inconvenient when I can't go to specific line (by path) in order to work with original JSON file (eg. scrolling, view with with syntax highlighting, editing).

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I didn't write it. I just did a google search; you may have better luck than I did. But the answer to your original question is almost certainly going to be a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij:

File must be stored with extension .json5

Edit -> Find -> Evaluate Json path Expression

it will open another window, where you will get two opinions.

- output: Path expression : will give you the json path of all the elements in the json.
- output: Matching Value: you write your path and it will return the corresponding value.

[image]